# Proper configuring of Multibranch Pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I properly configure a Multibranch Pipeline in Jenkins when Git is selected as branch source? I get a "Does not meet criteria" for every branch that is checked in the branch indexing log.

Answer (score 6):

This Multibranch Pipeline job will create a pipeline job if your Git branch contains a Jenkinsfile.

This Jenkinsfile describe how to build the current branch (Jenkins Groovy DSL).

If your branch doesn't contain a Jenkinsfile, then you will get this "does not meet criteria" message.

More information about the Multibranch pipeline [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/#creating-multibranch-pipelines).

Comment: So no other reason for that message showing up? Because I did actually include a Jenkinsfile in one of the branches..

Comment: If your Jenkinsfile has the relevant name & case, I don't see other reason. Can you add a screen copy of your multibranch pipeline job?

Comment: I can provide a screen copy, however, first I can mention that I also tried creating a simple Pipeline, where I write the pipeline script in the Jenkins UI. Here I have a git url: *URL to project* step. Then I get the following errors: 


ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from *URL to project*

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags –progress *URL to project*  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:

Comment: @heydy Is your repo a large one? Could i take more than 10 mins to do a git clone from the server where you have jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure your `Jenkinsfile` does **not** have a `.groovy` extension

Answer (score 2):

At least on Windows the casing of the Jenkinsfile is important. It has to be with an uppercase "J" and the rest lowercase.

```
Jenkinsfile
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to check the script type. The first line of "Jenkinsfile" had to be:
"#!groovy"

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno Lavit points out the criteria is pretty simple.

I believe you may have an issue with your current branch.

In a clean environment, try to checkout the branch and verify that the Jenkinsfile is indeed included and that is it a valid text file.
I had a similar issue in the past where my push did not finished correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your jenkins plugin (Git plugin and Git Client plugin) is old.
Try to update the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this when I added Jenkinsfile **after** I had created the Multibranch Pipeline project. The solution was to delete the project and create again :)

Still, for some Jenkins-only-know reason, it doesn't run the build on my master branch now.