# Getting Build Failure Error in Jenkins while trying to clone the private repo from GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting the following error while cloning the private GitHub repo in Jenkins.

`Fetching origin...
Pruning stale remotes...
Getting remote branches...
Checking branch master
Does not meet criteria
Done.
Finished: SUCCESS`

I have added SSH key to my repo in GitHub.
What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Did you check this? https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344936/proper-configuring-of-multibranch-pipeline-in-jenkins), you get the "Does not meet criteria" message when the branch does not have a Jenkinsfile. Does your branch master have a Jenkinsfile?